# Oracle MAF : Deployment error when using cordova plugin

Tags: java, cordova, cordova-plugins, oracle-maf

I have tried to integrate cordova plugin into Oracle MAF application for accessing different feature like Image Capture, Audio and Video.

For sample, I have tried with [cordova-plugin-media-capture](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) from Github. Following is the workaround, I have added downloaded plugin into Additional Plugins in MAF application.

Please note, I have plugin outside of the project since I got issue when having it inside the project. (You may get the details by checking edit history of this post).

Now when I try to deploy the app i'm getting **`INTERNAL_ERROR`**, below is the stacktrace for your reference.

**Error Log:**

```
[06:07:41 PM] Installing "org.apache.cordova.network-information" for android
[06:07:41 PM] Installing "cordova-plugin-media-capture" for android
[06:07:41 PM] Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file" via plugin registry
[06:07:41 PM] Error Code : INTERNAL_ERROR
[06:07:41 PM] npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file
[06:07:41 PM] npm oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[06:07:41 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.runProcess(Unknown Source)
[06:07:41 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.executeCmd(Unknown Source)
[06:07:41 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.addPlugin(Unknown Source)
[06:07:41 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.deploy(Unknown Source)
[06:07:41 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.MafHelperMain.main(Unknown Source)
[06:07:41 PM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[06:07:41 PM] ... 5 more
[06:07:41 PM] Caused by: java.lang.Exception
[06:07:41 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException.<init>(Unknown Source)
[06:07:41 PM] ... 5 more
[06:07:41 PM] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
[06:07:41 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[06:07:41 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[06:07:41 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[06:07:41 PM] An error occurred deploying Cordova plugins. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.android.deployers.plugins.AndroidPluginDeployer)
```

I googled and [got the link for this issue](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3669595). Below are my try, But none of them works.

- Shorten android sdk path, application path, plugin path.
- All path without space.
- Ran the JDeveloper as Administrator.

Please share your ideas, if you have any.

Comment: i face same problem what to do

Comment: whether you kept plugin outside of the project, meaning in your local system?

Comment: @YogeshDoke I have also answered the workaround which I followed for this issue on below. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, Keep the plugin outside of the project (*Your local drive of the system*) and refer in the **maf-application.xml** file using below steps.

- Go to <kbd>Application Resources</kbd> block in JDeveloper.
- Open **maf-application.xml** under <kbd>Description</kbd> -> <kbd>ADF
  META-INF</kbd> folder.
- **maf-application.xml** file gets open, make sure you have select the ***Overview*** mode.
- Then follow this tutorial ([Registering Additional Plugins in Your MAF Application](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf210/mobile/develop/maf-apps-integrate-plugins.htm#ADFMF25057)) for adding additional plugin (which you want to use).
- Make sure you have *unchecked unwanted Core-Plugins* (Like *Camera* - when you add cordova media capture plugin). Since this lets to conflict MAF application, which one need to be used while building the deployment file.
- You can open **maf-plugin.xml** file to confirm whether additional plugin have been added or not.

That's it, deploy the application and check.

Comment: which plugin i have to put outside of my project i beginners

Comment: i am deploying on android device

Comment: whether you are using any plugin in your app?

Comment: Here I used "cordova-plugin-media-capture" plugin to capture image/audio/video. So I downloaded plugin from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture as zip file and unzip it in my local drive. It can be any drive, later you need to refer it in  maf-application.xml file.

Comment: can i upload my maf android app on playstore,somewhere i heard about oracle licence fees like this for per user :120USD Single User Update and Support:26.40USD All user Processor :5,800USD All user Update and support 1,276.00USD i don't understand this cost

Comment: if want to upload it on google playstore and as its web application so server on google cloud platform is it valid,can i implement this things with maf

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen where the plugins.xml file gets corrupted over time.  If this happens, clear all of the plugins manually in maf-plugin.xml.  Then, re-select the required plugins within maf-application.xml.